# Java EE Enterprise Application: perform some action on deploy/startup

Tags: java, deployment, jakarta-ee, entity, startup

I would like to perform some action as soon as my application (Enterprise Application with Business Logic, EJB, and a Client, Web) is deployed.
For example I would like to make some entity in a persistent state, or otherwise create a file.
How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Configure [`SerlvetContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and override `contextInitilized()`

in your web application description , web.xml

```
<web-app ...>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.someCompany.AppNameServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app
```

---

```
package com.someCompany;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class AppNameServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("ServletContextListener destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("ServletContextListener started");   
                // do the things here 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well... I'm a little newbie with JEE.
How can I configure a ContextListener?

Comment: @Mauro hit F5 , added information

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to try that... I'll let you know.

Comment: **Even Easier Now…** The [@WebListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) annotation added to [Servlet 3.0 spec](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) now gives you this behavior without the bother of editing the *web.xml* file. See this illuminating [answer by BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9186070/642706).

Answer (score 0):

The "default" way is to have a servlet with an init() method. Then in the servlet-descriptor you mark this servlet as load-on-startup 1:

Example:

```
<servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamResourceServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

As soon as the servlet is deployed (which happens after the EJBs are deployed), that init() method is called and you can execute the task you want.

Answer (score 0):

With present web application in your ear, the easiest and simplest would be to use ServletContextListener, otherwise in EJB 3.1 you could use automatic timers or startup singleton session beans.