# javaEE EAR-project something like onload or startup method

Tags: jakarta-ee, startup, ear

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java EE Enterprise Application: perform some action on deploy/startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120831/java-ee-enterprise-application-perform-some-action-on-deploy-startup)

Is there a way to define something like a on load method for a javaEE ear server application.

For example I use Hibernate on a JBoss EAR Server which needs one SessionFactory instance for the whole application lifetime.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6120831/838434

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do stuff during webapp's startup.
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do stuff during webapp's shutdown.
    }

}
```

or a [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) (particularly useful if you plan to implement "open session in view" pattern)

```
@WebFilter("*.xhtml") // Or whatever URL pattern
public class OpenSessionInViewFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // Do stuff during filter's init (so, during webapp's startup).
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Do stuff during every request on *.xhtml (or whatever URL pattern)
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Do stuff during filter's destroy (so, during webapp's shutdown).
    }

}
```