# Run code during startup of EAR deployment, not in WAR

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, startup, ear

I need some tasks performed on deployment/redeployment of a package (EAR/JAR/WAR) into Wildfly. Is there any standard way how to run some code on deployment?

I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120831/java-ee-enterprise-application-perform-some-action-on-deploy-startup) that in the case of WAR deployment it is possible to create a servlet that will implement  `ServletContextListener` and hook the required task on it, however I would need a more general solution that is not dependent just on WAR.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Startup and @PostConstruct is the way to go for you.

A method annotated with @PostConstruct is executed as soon as in instance of the containing class is created. To ensure your class is created as soon as the app is deployed, Annotate the class with @Startup (and maybe @ApplicationSoped or @Singleton).