# Display application context path after deployment on Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, ant

I want to echo application-context path after deployment on local tomcat. It might be done using maven or ant. All information I have is CATALINA_HOME variable. I tried using cargo plugin for maven, but it doesnt display context path after deployment, I also tried tomcat deploy plugin, but it requires me to specify tomcat manager path, as well as user and password.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Implement a `ServletContextListener` and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120831/java-ee-enterprise-application-perform-some-action-on-deploy-startup)

```
final String contextPath = servletContextEvent.getServletContext().getContextPath();
System.out.println("context path = " + contextPath);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cant check this out now. I need this context path to be displayed in shell where i called deploy command. Will this listener echo context path to shell or tomcat log?

Comment: if your deploy command waits till it deploys and streams the tomcat log back